# Machine reboots after 30 minutes, or never

Tags: linux, ubuntu, reboot

I have a [machine](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/intense-pc/) (using it as server) that have had some weird boot issues for some time now. Either, it stays up running till next time I reboot it manually (kernel upgrades and so on), or it reboots at around the `29m50s` mark.

I took a [video](https://youtu.be/XqyZJbRThJA?t=16) when it happened. It just dies.. With the same `click` as when I turn it off from the OS.

I am not able to find any logic to when it stays up, or when it reboots.

Examples:

- reboots @ 0:29:50
- manual reboot, because it was @ 24h+
- reboots @ 0:29:53
- reboots 0:29:50
- manual reboot, was on for 35+ minutes
- reboots @ 0:29:54
- reboots @ 0:29:54
- manual reboot, was on for 12+ hours.
- manual reboot, was on for 35+ minutes.
- reboots @ 0:29:54
- reboots @ 0:29:52
- reboots @ 0:29:50

These tests was spread over the last 2 days. I am running `while true; do echo $(awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime; acpi -t; hddtemp /dev/sda); sleep 1; done` to see updated uptime and temp info when it shuts down.

An example output being `0:29:54 Thermal 0: ok, 50.0 degrees C Thermal 1: ok, 50.0 degrees C /dev/sda: ST1000LM014-1EJ164: 47°C`.

I also take output of `ps -eo args | sort | uniq`, and `systemctl list-units` on each boot up. But I see no diff in those.

The logs `journalctl --follow` and `dmesg -wH` (both follow versions, so I will get the output before boot), shows nothing. Nor any other logs I could find.

How can I troubleshoot this? Something like `strace` but for every process at the same time would be wonderful.

One theory is that there is something booting it at an 30min (exact) mark, but that thing starts before the systems uptime ticks. But what can that be?

**lsb_release -a**

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Release:        16.04
- Codename:       xenial

**uname -a**

- Linux d0 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**hw**

- Intense-PC from CompuLab Ltd.
- cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517UE CPU @ 1.70GHz

Comment: Maybe it helps to search the web for services etc. with a timeout of 30 min.

Comment: It's almost "vanilla" ubuntu. I turned off a lot of services as well. I would imagine a service timing out and sending a shutdown to the cpu would put something in the logs..

Comment: Do you also tried to increase the log levels in ``dmesg`` and in ``/proc/sys/kernel/printk``? Another approach would be a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04, check that there's no problem and then successively make it similar to your system. Keep the diffs of ``/etc`` and ``dpkg --get-selections`` to know what's different.

Comment: try to recreate problem on live cd?  try to recreate problem on livecd and with barebones hardware?  Isolate man, isolate! :).

Comment: @bjhend nice tip. I will set the runlevels next time I check. Reinst is a pain tho, but I will try that if I need to..

Comment: @Damon hehe.. I had it at the ubuntu usb boot screen for hours, multiple times without it rebooting. Didn't try the full "OS" part of the livecd tho.

I started using the system now, so will probably not debug more till next upgrade